# How to handle multiple checkboxes whit PHP sent by jquery.ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending a form in async with jquery.ajax method. On the PHP side it receive the right array (I think), but for some reason it shows me an error message when I try to extract the checkboxes values with a normal cicle. What can I do to fix it?

This is the Warning message I see:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mybestfa/public_html/ajax/verifica.php on line 206

If I try to echo the given array, I see this below. I suppose that this string it's creating the issue because actually it doesn't seem to be like a normal array. It's like a GET string:
categoria%5B%5D=bellezza&categoria%5B%5D=educazione

So the final question is, how can I extract the checkboxes values from the array?

HTML:

```
          <form id="form_step1" action="ajax/verify.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            $query="SELECT name FROM category";
            $result=mysqli_query($connessione, $query);

            $num_check=0;

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $category_name=$row['name'];
              $num_check=$num_check+1;
              ?>
              <label for="check[<?php echo $num_check; ?>]">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check[<?php echo $num_check; ?>]" name="category[]" value="<?php echo $category_name; ?>">
              <?php echo $category_name; ?></label>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
            <p id="result_step1"><ul></ul></p>
            <input type="submit" id="button_step1" name="button_step1" class="form_button" value="Continue">
          </form>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form_step1").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var fields_step1=$('#form_step1').serialize();
          var submit_step1=$("#button_step1").val();

          $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/verify.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {fields_step1: fields_step1,
                  submit_step1: submit_step1},
            dataType: "text",

            success: function(risposta,status){
              console.log(risposta);

              if(status=="success") {
                $("#risultato_step1").html(risposta);
                if (risposta == "prosegui") {
                  $("#risultato").html("");
                }
              }
          })
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_step1']))
{
  $errorForm=false;

  $categories=$_POST['fields_step1'];
  foreach ($categories as $category)
  {
    echo "Founded: $category<br>";
  }
}
```

PS: I pasted the code translating the italian variables in english. So I apologize if I forgot to translate something along the road.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be like a normal array. It's like a GET string`...yep that's what `$('#form_step1').serialize()` has done. So you're putting already-serialised data into an object, which jQuery will then serialise again (when you pass it in via the `data` option). Therefore that part ends up double-serialised. When PHP deserialised the POST data, that part is still single-serialised, hence it's a string which you can't loop over.

Comment: You should normally just serialize the form and pass it to `data` directly e.g. `data: $('#form_step1').serialize()`. However serialize() won't capture your button field so `if(isset($_POST['submit_step1']))` won't be true - you'd perhaps be better to have a hidden field containing that value instead so it continues to be passed